# JQuery fullscreen gallery

Tags: jquery, supersized, fancybox-2

I'm using supersized plugin http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/ to obtain a fullscreen gallery.

It works fine itself, but I need to hide and show it only from a fancybox button and from an esc button. I'm using fancybox 2 and I want to implements fullscreen too, so I used supersized.

The question is: how can I hide supersized without compromising its behavior?

The answer is not simple as you think, because if you try to set 'display: none' to div#supersized, and other relative divs, when you display it the auto 'fit' of the images doesn't work...

If you set 'visibility: hidden' it seems to work, but when I want to see the first image for the first time, the box which should have to display the image is completely white.

You can see my test site for example: http://provaschiavello.altervista.org/Projects/STARFISH%20SQUARE%20|%20PIAZZA%20VITTORIO

Any suggestions?

Comment: Andrey, when I load your page, I see the images load just fine. Is there a specific browser where you're seeing this problem?

Comment: In effect it seems fine now, but if I clear the browser cache i'll see that issue again.
I'm using Firefox 10.0.4...

If I refresh the page without clearing my cache it works fine.

Comment: Update: in Chrome it works well, but some images are not visible at all in supersized, even though they are all in the slides array...

I suspect that supersized is not a robust plugin... Could you suggest me something else?

Comment: Sorry, best advice I can give is to pound the virtual pavement on the information superhighway and see what you can find, that's what I would do. Aside from that,  you could try to narrow the problem down yourself, post the code that you think is causing trouble, and give the community here time to answer. But without that, this is pretty tough to answer. Good luck! Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Sorry but I'm Italian, I don't understand what you mean with 'pound the virtual pavement on the information superhighway'...

Anyway I think i've resolved: the solution is to 'init' supersized when button is clicked the first time, and not on page load.
Thus there is no need to hide it because before clicking on fullscreen button it simply doesn't exist.
To switch between page and supersized then it's sufficient some fadeIn(), fadeOut() that don't influences its behavior.
Thanks the same!

Comment: lol sorry, It's an expression that means to get out there and look around. Usually people say they're going to "get out there and pound the pavement to look for a job", except in this case, you're google searching :)  Sorry for the ethnocentric confusion :)  By the way, if you solved your own problem, it's perfectly okay (and encouraged) for you to [answer your own question by posting an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/). Just be sure to include plenty of detail to answer it like you're answering any other question. Good luck! :)

Comment: I'm glad to see that you answered to me like to a compatriot! It means I have no very bad English :D
Anyway i'm posting the 'extended' solution right now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution (or the workaround):

Set this global variable: first = true;

Creates this two utility functions:

```
function fullScreen(n) {
    // Init supersized only at first time
    if (first) {
        jQuery(function($){
            $.supersized({
                // All the supersized 'options': 'value'
            });
        });
        first = false;
    }
    // Repeat this for each element of the page
    // which needs to be hided while supersized is running
    $('#myElem').fadeOut();

    // Show it
    $('#supersized-container').fadeIn();
    $('#supersized').fadeIn();
    api.goTo(n+1);
}

function closeFull() {
    $('#supersized-container').fadeOut();
    $('#supersized').fadeOut();

    // Same as above
    $('#myElem').fadeIn();
}
```

And then use them to switch between supersized and your normal page.

NB: The argument of fullScreen (n) is the index passed to the supersized gallery.

Enjoy. :)